# Cannot find the Outliers (More specifically the IQR) of my data set

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Trying to find the outliers of an excel sheet using pandas in python. I am able to find the first and third quartiles, but cannot subtract one from the other without returning `NaN`.

**Here is the essential code:**

```
absent = pd.read_excel('Absenteeism_at_work.xls')

print("\nOUTLIERS:")
# q1 = (absent.loc[:741, ['Distance from Residence to Work']].quantile([0.25]))
# q3 = (absent.loc[:741, ['Distance from Residence to Work']].quantile([0.75]))

#print(absent.loc[:741, 'Distance from Residence to Work'].quantile([0.25])) #quartile

#print(q1)
# q1, q3 = absent.loc[:741, ['Distance from Residence to Work', 'Transportation expense', 'Month of absence',
  #                       'Social smoker', 'Social drinker', 'Education']].quantile([0.25 - 0.75])

print(absent.loc[:741, ['Distance from Residence to Work', 'Transportation expense', 'Month of absence',
                      'Social smoker', 'Social drinker', 'Education']].quantile([0.75])
   - absent.loc[:741, ['Distance from Residence to Work', 'Transportation expense', 'Month of absence',
                    'Social smoker', 'Social drinker', 'Education']].quantile([0.25]))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
OUTLIERS:
      Distance from Residence to Work  Transportation expense  \
0.25                              NaN                     NaN   
0.75                              NaN                     NaN   

      Month of absence  Social smoker  Social drinker  Education  
0.25               NaN            NaN             NaN        NaN  
0.75               NaN            NaN             NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You code is just simply quartile range calculation. if it can work for you, that will be fine. If you need true outlier detect which is more complicated than quartile based mode, especially multivariables you can resort to python package like sklearn or pyod.
2. using quantile functioni, you need clean the raw data to make sure it is numerica only. Especially, you import excel file as data source.
3. check data by

   tmp_df = absent.iloc[:741]

   cols =  ['Distance from Residence to Work', 
            'Transportation expense', 
            'Month of absence',
            'Social smoker', 
            'Social drinker',
            'Education']

   print(tmp_df[col].quantile(0.25,0.75))

   print(tmp_df[col].describe(include='all'))

Good luck.

WY